# Problems with Unit Testing in C++ (Visual studio 2022)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, enums, include

Issues with unit testing

I cant really see what is going wrong with that code, but something doesn't include right
relevant files:

##### MetaData.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
enum ChessColor
{
    White,
    Black
};
enum PieceType
{
   King,
   Queen,
   Rook,
   Bishop,
   Knight,
   Pawn,
   None
};
const int BOARD_SIZE = 8;

std::string getLongNameOfChessType(PieceType* type);
std::string getShortNameOfChessType(PieceType* type);

std::string getLongNameOfChessColor(ChessColor* color);
std::string getShortNameOfChessColor(ChessColor* color);
```

##### MetaData.cpp

```
#include "MetaData.h"

std::string getLongNameOfChessType(PieceType* type)
{
    switch (*type)
    {
    case PieceType::King:
        return "King";
    case PieceType::Queen:
        return "Queen";
    case PieceType::Rook:
        return "Rook";
    case PieceType::Bishop:
        return "Bishop";
    case PieceType::Knight:
        return "Knight";
    case PieceType::Pawn:
        return "Pawn";
    default:
        return "NoType";
    }
}

std::string getShortNameOfChessType(PieceType* type)
{
    switch (*type)
    {
    case PieceType::King:
        return "K";
    case PieceType::Queen:
        return "Q";
    case PieceType::Rook:
        return "R";
    case PieceType::Bishop:
        return "B";
    case PieceType::Knight:
        return "N";
    case PieceType::Pawn:
        return "P";
    default:
        return "NoType";
    }
}
std::string getLongNameOfChessColor(ChessColor* color)
{
    switch (*color)
    {
    case ChessColor::White:
        return "White";
    case ChessColor::Black:
        return "Black";
    default:
        return "NoColor";
    }
}
std::string getShortNameOfChessColor(ChessColor* color)
{
    switch (*color)
    {
    case ChessColor::White:
        return "W";
    case ChessColor::Black:
        return "B";
    default:
        return "NoColor";
    }
}
```

##### ChessTest.cpp

The test file.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <MetaData.h>
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace ChessTest
{
    TEST_CLASS(ChessTest)
    {
    public:
        
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            ChessColor c = ChessColor::Black;
            std::string actual = "B";
            std::string trying = getShortNameOfChessColor(&c);
            Assert::AreEqual(actual,trying);
        }
    };
}
```

So the errors i get are these

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl getShortNameOfChessColor(enum ChessColor *)" (?getShortNameOfChessColor@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PEAW4ChessColor@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl ChessTest::ChessTest::TestMethod1(void)" (?TestMethod1@ChessTest@1@QEAAXXZ)    ChessTest   C:\Users\censoredUsername\Desktop\prog\Chess\ChessProject\ChessTesting\ChessTest\ChessTest.obj  1
```

A few warnings

```
Warning C26812  The enum type 'PieceType' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).    ChessProject    C:\Users\censoredUsername\Desktop\prog\Chess\ChessProject\ChessProject\MetaData.cpp 3
Warning C26812  The enum type 'ChessColor' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).   ChessProject    C:\Users\censoredUsername\Desktop\prog\Chess\ChessProject\ChessProject\MetaData.cpp 44  
Warning C26812  The enum type 'ChessColor' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).   ChessTest   C:\Users\censoredUsername\Desktop\prog\Chess\ChessProject\ChessTesting\ChessTest\ChessTest.cpp  14
```

Error 2

```
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  ChessTest   C:\Users\censoredUsername\Desktop\prog\Chess\ChessProject\x64\Debug\ChessTest.dll   1
```

Some Extra info

I made a project, added some basic files and wanted to do a test driven development.
Thus i added a Native Unit Test Project to my current Project.
Described here: [MS Description to add unit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2022)

I coded in a lot of languages before, but have the most experience with java/c# (and as you know, these are very different to cpp)

I appreciate every comment/input for that matter.

Comment: Make absolutely certain that MetaData.cpp is being compiled and linked. If it hasn't been formally added to the project, Visual Studio will ignore it when building.

Comment: @user4581301 I added an existing item, like another user suggested:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72708823/17695886) but there is still an issue (see my comment under the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you used `#include <MetaData.h>`.

Use `Add Existing item` to add MetaData .h and .cpp. Or, you need to build static library for MetaData.

Comment: How do i do that?

I was unable to find the Syntax for that.

Comment: It is not syntax. Right click your project->Add->Existing Item.

Comment: Thanks that solved some issues.

Still got that error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C1010 unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source? ChessTest C:\Users\username\Desktop\prog\Chess\ChessProject\ChessProject\MetaData.cpp 68

                                                              and i certainly added pch.h, so i got no idea what i should do

Comment: Find the option in your project properties: C/C++-> All options->  Precomplied Headers. Change it to Not  using.

Comment: thanks that fixed it :D Do you have an idea how i get rid of this warning? Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning C26812 The enum type 'ChessColor' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3). ChessTest C:\Users\usrname\Desktop\prog\Chess\ChessProject\ChessTesting\ChessTest\ChessTest.cpp 13

Comment: The warning is another question. You can post a new thread to get more attention.